# No focus in the LibreOffice find dialogue

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, openoffice.org, kde4, oxygen

Since recently the find dialogue in my LibreOffice appears in the system window frame.

[image: find dialogue]

Probably as a result of this change, when I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search for a text string inside the document, the dialogue's text field isn't focused, so I cannot immediately type in the searched string. Instead, I have to either use a mouse click or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> once again first. This is annoying.

Any idea if the original behaviour can be restored by a setting? Any other solution?

Comment: Does this help? Go to Tools / Options / LibreOffice / View and set Mouse Positioning to "middle of dialog window".

Comment: Yes! I set the option as you suggested and restarted LibreOffice. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A commentator above suggested a pretty good workaround:

1. Go to Tools / Options / LibreOffice / View.
2. Set Mouse Positioning to "Dialog center".
3. Restart LibreOffice.

The find dialogue still has the system window border around it but clicking Ctrl + F puts focus in the text field so one can type immediately.

Comment: @chaskes Thank you. It **was** a lucky guess, I couldn't reproduce the error. Let the answer stand as it is, it is fine by me.

Comment: Alas, I haven't changed the settings but the single Ctrl + F stopped working again :(

Comment: On my LO 4.4.1.2 that setting makes no difference. But at least pressing ctrl+F again puts the focus on the text field. As far as I remember it has always been like this, so I guess the non-focus (with the default setting) isn't a bug per se, but pretty pretty stupid definitely.